# How to secure the communication between android app and door lock controller?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been working on a small project using android app over Bluetooth to control a servo motor (close or open lock). To authenticate the communication, I implement HMAC (with SHA256) on both the android app and the arduino controller.

When user press the button to unlock the door, it will generate a random code,  which will be seen as a message. Then HMAC is called to create a hash string with this message and the shared key. The final string sent to arduino would be  "randomcode+commmand+hashed-string"

```
Something like this:

 5uq0xboq82oih111e30774e4bf8302a04e71eb84c70ce2c130717304f52c67ce709203caea0ce5
(command and the random code are hidden in the string)
```

As the arduino received the message, it will break the string into three parts. The command, the random code and the hashed string. It will run HMAC with the shared key and the random code. Then compare that with the received hashed string. If matched, the perform the action (command).

This is my first project on implementing HMAC. I know this may be sort of subjective question but any comment on this implementation may helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How do you prevent replay attacks? Also, if someone can intercept the message; he could change the command part, and send it to the Arduino, and it will accept it. I'd hash the randomcode+command, not just the randomcode.

Comment: I am not an expert on this but I don't think replay attacks would work. HMAC deals with user authentication and validates data integrity. The command is just 1 or 0.  Adding it to the HMAC or not wouldn't make much difference, I think. The arduino controller will not execute any command unless the HMAC message is matched.

Comment: HMAC only does the authentication part. Since you don't hash the command, it doesn't do anything for data integrity. HMAC also doesn't solve the replay attack problem. Unless the Arduino stores all previous randomCodes, and rejects if they are re-used again. What would happen if you send a "door open" message, I intercept the message, and resend it after you've gone for work? The hash will match!

Comment: I could append the command to the random code, if it will make any difference. Someone may be able to guess what it may be. Intercepting the message is indeed possible as there is no secure communication channel, however my findings show that you would have to know the shared key in order to have a matched HMAC hash. So as long as the shared key is not compromised, the application will be safe and sound. No?

Comment: You still haven't solved to the replay-attack problem. The attacked doesn't need to "decyper" the message. It just needs to store it, and play it back later. This is the third time I brought this up. Why do you think your solutions isn't vulnerable to it?

Comment: it is wide-open to replay as described. you just need to generate the random salt on the ardunio (easier said than done), send it to the app, let the app create the derivation, send the arduino the result to dis-assemble and compare. that way, old keys won't work and the app itself cannot mint valid keys.

Comment: Thank you both for raising the alarm! I started with generating a random code from Arduino but walked away when finding that's not an easy task. Having your input,  I should go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Generating the random code from arduino controller as soon as the connection is being established and set a time limit such as 30 seconds, after that the code will no longer valid, should address the replay attack, at least for an application such as door lock control.